# Div content vertical accordion

Tags: jquery, accordion

I have vertical div list and I am trying to create a content accordion.

The layout looks like approximately like this:

```
<div class='item'>
   <li class='title'>...some a tag here...</li>
   <div class='content'></div>
</div>
<div class='item'>
   <li class='title'>...some a tag here...</li>
   <div class='content'></div>
</div>
```

div class item should be listed one below other, div class content should be hidden, and on click div class item, the content should expand vertically.

Can someone make me a basic setup? I cant get this going.

Keep in mind that its not necessary to have exact same layout (div and li elements within), I can change this and modify on my side if there is a better way to organize this.

I am using jquery.

Comment: Please note that it is also invalid HTML to place `<li>` tags inside anything other than `<ul>` or `<ol>` tags. Whilst this will still render it is not inline with HTML specs.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, I was just shortening code for the demo.

Comment: @Toniq please check my answer. and tick the green mark if it helped your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**you didn't need any jquery plugin**
check this **http://jsfiddle.net/modaloda/3R2Jd/1/**

```
        $(document).ready(function () {

        $(".title").click(function () {

            $(".content").slideUp("fast");

            $(this).find('.expand').removeClass('collapse');
            if ($(this).next().is(":hidden") == true )
            {
                $('.expand').removeClass('collapse');
                $(this).next().slideDown("normal")
                $(this).find('.expand').addClass('collapse');
            }
        }); 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It is much easier to use 3rd Party tools to do features like this, there a hundreds of plugins to add this functionality and many of them are free.

One of my personal favourites (and I don't doubt one of the Community favourites) is [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/)

jQuery UI has an Accordion feature that can be easily used.

[See here for examples](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/)

You simply add the plugin to the page and structure your content in a certain way to make this work.

Example :

```
<div id="accordion">
   <h3>...some a tag here...</h3>
   <div class='content'></div>
   <h3>...some a tag here...</h3>
   <div class='content'></div>
</div>
```

jQuery : `$( "#accordion" ).accordion();`

And now you have fully working jQuery Accordions! There are many different properties that you can change to make it more customized.